# Basic shopping cart with empty list in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I can't seem to get this basic code working?
I'm tryin to allow people to choose from the given items in available list, check if userInput == available_items, append them to my empty list & allow for users to continue, quit and print their items.
Any help is appreciated!

```
available_items = ['Yogurt', 'Hummus', 'Bananas', 'Stawberries', 'Crackers', 'Veggie Pack', 'Shaving Cream', 'Razors', 'Deodorant' ]
userItems=[]
shopping_1st = True
while shopping_1st:
    userInput = input("Hello valued guest! Choose from the selection of available items to be added to your cart. ")
    response = input("'y' = Continue shopping?  'n' = continue to cart ")
    if str.lower(response) == 'n':
       shopping_1st = False
    elif str.upper(userInput) != available_items:
       print("Item not available:")
       print("Select from available items:")
    else:
        userItems.append(str.lower(userInput))
    for userInput in userItems:
        print(userInput)
```

Comment: You seem to have misread some part about the upper/lower methods for strings. Yes, the syntax is `str.lower()`, but you put the actual name of the string in place of `str`, and not as an argument.

Comment: @Anonymous4045 There is nothing wrong with `str.lower(my_string)`. Python's `str` class actually implements those static methods. It's just more verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues:

1. `str.upper(userInput) != available_items` will try to compare a string with a list, which will always return `False`.
2. `.upper` converts all letters to UPPERCASE. Consider using [`.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title).

Try

```
...
elif userInput.title() not in available_items:
...
```

Comment: Much appreciated thanks! Had no clue that comparing a string to a list would return false every time. Ya learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
available_items = ['Yogurt', 'Hummus', 'Bananas', 'Stawberries', 'Crackers', 'Veggie Pack', 'Shaving Cream', 'Razors', 'Deodorant' ]
userItems=[]
shopping_1st = True

while shopping_1st:
    userInput = input("Hello valued guest! Choose from the selection of available items to be added to your cart. ")

    if str.capitalize(userInput) not in available_items:
        print("Item not available:")
        print("Select from available items:")
    else:
        userItems.append(str.lower(userInput))

    response = input("'y' = Continue shopping?  'n' = continue to cart ")
    if str.lower(response) == 'n':
       shopping_1st = False       

for userInput in userItems:
    print(userInput)
```

Comment: I myself would have written entire code in a different way. Here I just tried to make your code work by doing the minimum editing I could do. There are better ways to perform the string operations you have tried. Anyways, welcome to the world of Python

Comment: Yes true .title() is to be used here. My apologies I didnt see the list items carefully and assumed there were one word items only. Thanks for reminding me.